# How to validate two instances of the same entity?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

## Use case

I am learning Symfony2 and am creating a Table Tennis tracking app to learn the framework. I have configured my entities as follows.

```
Player 1..n Result n..1 Match
```

On my form I'd like to validate that the scores for a match are correct.

## Implementation

`Match` has an `ArrayCollection()` of `results`.

My `MatchType` and `ResultType` forms contain the following.

```
 // Form\MatchType
    $builder->add('matchType', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'PingPongMatchesBundle:MatchType',
            'property' => 'name',
        )
    )
    ->add('results', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ResultType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        )
    )
    ->add('notes');

 // Form\ResultType
    $builder->add('player', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PingPongPlayerBundle:Player',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->orderBy('p.firstName', 'ASC');
                },
            ))
            ->add('score');
```

## Issue

I need to be able to validate the scores. However I'm not sure how to approach this type of validation as I need to compare two instances of my `Result#score` in order to know if they are valid or not.

Is anyone able to suggest a method or approach that I could use in order to be able to compare `Result#score` between the two different instances? Can I validate the `ArrayCollection` in the `Match` entity for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could creat a custom validator constraint on Match entity.
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but your answer is too brief to constitute a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in **Callback** constraint:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but your answer is too brief to constitute a proper answer.